# When trying to fix a USB wifi adapter, I accidently killed the built in wifi adapter too. How can I fix this?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, dkms

After a recent update my USB wifi adapter quit working.The built-in adapter worked, but it is not compatible with 5ghz. Somehow in my attempt to fix the USB wifi, I killed the internal one too. I am only able to access the internet using USB tethering with my phone.  One of the last things I did before the internal wifi quit working was to remove a file cfg80211. Below is the diagnostic data that I hope will help someone assist me in resolving the internal wifi adapter so at least I have that.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 27 Apr 2022 17:15 CDT -0500

Booted last: 27 Apr 2022 00:00 CDT -0500

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.13.0-40-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 4 09:38:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:81ef]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0eef:c04d D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalaxTouch EXC3000-0367-44.01.00
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05c8:022a Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Webcam
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:b008 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
platform_profile       16384  1 hp_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.107.86/24 brd 192.168.107.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 3591sec preferred_lft 3591sec
    inet6 fe80::a45c:12e5:ae4a:1cd5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.107.141 dev usb0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.107.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.107.86 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[644 root '/etc/resolv.conf']
nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         863       1  0 17:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         usb0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.13.0-40-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/net/usb0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       usb0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       8fee193d-edfc-3f27-a634-d3cecb149e8b
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.107.86/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.107.141
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.107.141, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.107.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.107.141
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3599
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.107.141
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1651101339
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = mrpbell5
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.107.86
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        next_server = 192.168.107.141
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.107.141
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::a45c:12e5:ae4a:1cd5/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/24
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   8fee193d-edfc-3f27-a634-d3cecb149e8b | Wired connection 2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E0_D0_83_C2_1F_74
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/8
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   81a72a28-8664-411d-b177-c115c6ef2d99 | EDDIE's S10+ Network

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp7s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.13.0-40-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp7s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:07:00.0/net/enp7s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/StacysDadIsReallyReallyRad.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=StacysDadIsReallyReallyRad | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=StacysDadIsReallyReallyRad
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wyndris306.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wyndris306 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Wyndris306
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ThereAreFourLights.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ThereAreFourLights | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ThereAreFourLights
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CenturyLink1689_5G 1.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CenturyLink1689_5G 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=CenturyLink1689_5G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/StacysDadIsReallyReallyRad 1.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=StacysDadIsReallyReallyRad 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=StacysDadIsReallyReallyRad
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CenturyLink1689.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CenturyLink1689 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=CenturyLink1689
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/KAI_SU_TEKNON.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=KAI_SU_TEKNON | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=KAI_SU_TEKNON
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SHPA-Staff.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SHPA-Staff | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SHPA-Staff
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

nl80211 not found.

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp7s0    no frequency information.

usb0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp7s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/8821cu.conf]
options 8821cu rtw_drv_log_level=0 rtw_led_ctrl=1 rtw_vht_enable=1 rtw_power_mgnt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   12.257869] r8169 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: Link is Down
[  181.778003] rndis_host 2-3:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, RNDIS device, <MAC address>
[  306.509105] rndis_host 2-3:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-3, RNDIS device
[  352.392867] rndis_host 2-3:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, RNDIS device, <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]>

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: I believe that you want to reinstall the driver for the USB adapter and blacklist the internal device so that the two do not conflict. However, in your readings above, the USB is not shown. Please insert it and run: `lsusb`. Next edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 At this point I want to enable the internal wifi adapter and deal with the USB one at some future point. Tthere's a weird issue with it in Windows too so I am going to replace it but I need the internal adapter to work in the interim.

Comment: @chil555 your solution worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reinstall the driver and its dependent components for the built-in wireless device, do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Reboot.